# how to group ages in specific range using r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(age = c(40,42,43,45,47,48,51,50,55),
                 amount = c(456,487,789,231,454,525,421,478,789))
```

How can I group this age in to `seq(40,55,by=5)` and find the aggregate sum of these groups?

I have tried tried

```
aggregate(df$amount, by = list(df$age) , sum)
```

But it gives me only sum of same age, and I need the age it to be grouped and their aggregate sum.

Comment: If you have tried something already and just need help with that attempt, then include the rest of your code please.

Comment: where should 45 lie? fro 40-45 or from 45-50?

Comment: `aggregate(.~age,transform(df,age=findInterval(age,seq(40,55,by=5),all.inside = T)),sum)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cut` to group the ages and then `aggregate` the amounts.

```
Age <- cut(df$age, c(seq(40, 55, by = 5), Inf), include.lowest = TRUE)

aggregate(amount ~ Age, df, sum)
#      Age amount
#1 [40,45]   1963
#2 (45,50]   1457
#3 (50,55]   1210
```

Comment: Thanks. Now what if I want to again categorize the age group based on their gender and find its aggregate? could you please help?

Comment: @vinuraj_pg You would change the formula to include gender. Something like `amount ~ Age + gender`. The rest of the `aggregate` call would be the same.